# Redux form "change" is called twice

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

i'm using a toggle input which i wrap with redux form. When i click on it i want my redux field value to change in a specific way. So in mapDispatchToProps i wrote this code:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, { cardNumber }) => ({
  onAtmLimitToggle: (atmLimitValue) => {
    if (atmLimitValue) {
      dispatch(change(cardNumber, 'atmLimit', 0));
    } else {
      dispatch(change(cardNumber, 'atmLimit', 100));
    }
  }
});
```

My Field's code is this:

```
<Field
        id={`atmLimit${cardIndex}`}
        name=atmLimit
        component="input"
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={() => onAtmLimitToggle(atmLimitValue)}
      />
```

When i click on the button the redux form change function is called twice as you can see in the screenshots[image]

To make things worse the second time that this is called it has wrong payload. I dont call change in other parts of the code. Why is this happening? I've also used e.stopPropagation but didnt work

[image]

Comment: You screenshot is a little bit weird, one tiny picture inside huge white space area. Could you maybe fix it?

Comment: from where you are getting the atmlimitvalue ?

Comment: The atmlimitvalue  is from the parent..nothing special

Comment: @O4epegb I add the second screenshot. Sorry for the size